# analogy for pearson r statistics for binary classification task

Tags: statistics, correlation

I am trying to get idea how variables of my data correspond to target variable (binary class).

In regression, Pearson r statistic is quite good to get sense of variables relationship. Also I can use it for classification, treating classes 0 and 1 as real values but it's a risky trick.

My question: is there any equivalent statistic saying which variable is good for classification task ? Thanks

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to put some number on the strength of the relationship between a binary variable and some other variable (continuous, nominal, ordinal, binary)? And that, if the relationship is *strong*, you wanna use the other variable to predict the binary variable? I guess it is, in any case, important to specify what kind of variable the other variable is